# How do I a space between elements of flatMap function?

Tags: javascript, flatmap

I am putting together a Pokédex application for a school project.
My tutor suggested I use a flatMap function to display pokémon types and abilities as there is sometimes more than one.

However, they just get listed with commas between them and no spacing. I'd like to add some spacing between the pokémon types. Can anyone help me with how to do that?

Code below for how I get the data:

```
function loadDetails(pokemon) {
    let url = pokemon.detailsUrl
    return fetch(url)
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json()
        })
        .then(function (details) {
            pokemon.imageUrl = details.sprites.front_default
            pokemon.height = details.height
            pokemon.weight = details.weight
            pokemon.abilities = details.abilities.flatMap(
                (element) => element.ability.name
            )
            pokemon.types = details.types.flatMap(
                (element) => element.type.name
            )
        })
        .catch(function (e) {
            console.error(e)
        })
}
```

Code below for how it is displayed:

```
function showModal(pokemon) {
    let modalBody = $('.modal-body')
    let modalTitle = $('.modal-title')

    //empty the modal before we start
    modalTitle.empty()
    modalBody.empty()

    // create the elements we want in the modal
    let nameElement = $(
        '<h1 class="text-capitalize">' + pokemon.name + '</h1>'
    )
    let imageElement = $('<img class="modal-img">')
    imageElement.attr('src', pokemon.imageUrl)
    let heightElement = $(
        '<p>' + '<b>Height: </b>' + pokemon.height + '</p>'
    )
    let weightElement = $(
        '<p>' + '<b>Weight: </b>' + pokemon.weight + '</p>'
    )
    let typesElement = $(
        '<p class="text-capitalize">' +
            '<b>Types: </b>' +
            pokemon.types +
            '</p>'
    )
    let abilitiesElement = $(
        '<p class="text-capitalize">' +
            '<b>Abilities: </b>' +
            pokemon.abilities +
            '</p>'
    )

    // append the elements to the modal
    modalTitle.append(nameElement)
    modalBody.append(imageElement)
    modalBody.append(heightElement)
    modalBody.append(weightElement)
    modalBody.append(typesElement)
    modalBody.append(abilitiesElement)

    $('#detailsmodal').modal()
}
```

Comment: Hey Mareeana - The `.flatMap()` method returns an array. In this case it is an array of Strings (presumably the `.name` property is a String). An array is simply a data structure and has nothing to do with how that data is displayed. So, since you didn't include any code that shows "_they just get listed with commas between them and no spacing._", there isn't enough information to help you. If you are simply using `console.log()`, then that is the default output for an array. If you want specialized output, you'll need to iterator over each element and add spaces to each.

Comment: Hi @RandyCasburn, thank you so much for your comment and sorry about that. I think I have added the relevant portion now.

Comment: You’re currently relying on the default `toString` of arrays. Consider using something like `Array.join` instead to control the resulting string.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thank you, this has solved it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you currently have as result (with commas) is the string representation of an array. You could use `join()` to join the array with a space.

```js
const pokemons = ["Charmander", "Bulbasaur", "Squirtle"];

console.log(`${pokemons}`); // string representation of array (,)
console.log(pokemons.join(" ")); // spaces ( )
```

Answer (score 2):

I used Array.join to control how the information is displayed, like so:

```
let abilitiesElement = $(
            '<p class="text-capitalize">' +
                '<b>Abilities: </b>' +
                pokemon.abilities.join(', ') +
                '</p>'
        )
```